# Creating a list based on a range in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of items available for sale in one sheet, with a unique SKU for each along with titles, locations, and more.
In another sheet, I want to create what we call a "pick list" where I can let a user input a list of SKUs, and have that sheet get the related Title, Location_Unit, and Location_Shelf column values from the other sheet so those items can be physically located.  I'm well aware this would work better in a database than a spreadsheet, but I work with what I have for now if possible.  Here is the database I'm working from, with sample data populated and a sample set of SKUs in the Pick List sheet. I'm not sure if I should use the FILTER function or INDEX/MATCH, or something else, or if I should consider a script instead of a function.  I've tried reading through similar questions and I'm currently lost.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x-FuM5BCVLnJry2u-L6MMGkTfirtvhZPN0OGQ9i3QCE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in Pick List B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=query(Main!A:O,"select D,K,L where H="&A2&" ",0)
```

Comment: Thank you!  So the query function can do that.  I think I understand what you wrote, but I'll have to make sure to do some more study so I can do more things like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pnuts' great solution, you can also try clearing out all content of B:D (in sheet 'Pick List') and then enter in B1

```
={"Title", "Location_Unit", "Location_Shelf"; Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Main!H:L, Main!D:D}, {6, 4, 5}, 0)),))}
```

This formula doesn't need to be copied down, as it is capable of outputting an array.